# Kafka Console Producer returns nothing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Hi I'm going through the [quick start](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) and I'm running into an error where when I type in `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic first`

I get nothing back when I'm expecting a text input to send the message to the Kafka producer. I have followed the instructions for a single and multi-broker set up but it doesn't seem like anything is working. My Zookeeper is running and I see the log files created in the correct log directories but nothing regarding my message.

I have also tried piping it like so `cat test.txt | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic first` or `echo test message | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic first`

Is there any other gotchas I should check out for?

Comment: I think the recent versions of the console producer should give a `>` prompt where you can type and send your message. The text you see in the quickstart is the user input. Are you getting a particular error?

Comment: Nope it just returns me back to the command line. I tried adding the `>` prompt as well @vahid

Comment: What version of Kafka distribution are you using?

Comment: I don't understand what kind of output are expecting from the producer. Are you running a consumer as well to check if the message is received by Kafka and read by the consumer itself ?

Comment: @ppatierno I'm following the Quickstart tutorial for Kafka and in it when you run a producer, you are prompted a text input field. I was unable to manually input anything in the Producer so my queue is empty and I'm unable to consumer anything with my Consumer.

Comment: it's really strange are you saying that you launch the console producer and the ">" isn't showed and if you try to type something it isn't showed in the command line ?

Comment: I had the same issue, the reason is kafka-console-producer.sh is empty. I went to  the github copy and paste the kafka-console-producer.sh file. Then all works.

Answer (score 4):

The same thing happened to me. surprisingly bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat  file had a size of 0. Just replaced with original file and it worked.